# ESLint not working in VS Code with JHipster app

Tags: visual-studio-code, jhipster, eslint

I am trying to get VS Code to show ESLint errors and warnings in a JHipster app. It does show brief popup errors from ESLint via "SnoreToast", but I can't find the details of the errors because nothing is highlighted in the editor window itself.

Since the generated JHipster app is so substantial, I assume it should already be correctly configured for ESLint. But it doesn't seem to be working, and I'm not sure what to do to fix it. (I am relatively new to JHipster, VS Code, and ESLint.)

I have installed the ESLint plugin in VS Code, but that hasn't made a different.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Edit] As requested, here is the output of "npm run lint":

```
 D:\{...}main\webapp\app\entities\bundle\bundle-detail.tsx
  21:3  error  Member getDerivedStateFromProps should be declared before all instance method definitions  @typescript-eslint/member-ordering
  39:9  error  'obj' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead                                             prefer-const
  40:9  error  'simple1' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead                                         prefer-const

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)
  2 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! prototype@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT lint: `eslint . --ext .js,.ts,.jsx,.tsx`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the prototype@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\g.t\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-10T11_57_45_154Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does it work from command line when you run `npm run lint`?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks! Yes and no. It does list three errors discovered in my code by ESLint. But then it ends with "npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE" ... "errno 1"  ... "Failed at the prototype@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT lint script" ... "This is probably not a problem with npm". There is a reference to another log, but I can't make much sense of it.

Comment: Please edit your question with output of npm run lint

Comment: So everything is fine in command line, fix the issues either manually or using `npm run lint:fix`, see package.json scripts section for other commands

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks. Running "npm run lint" is certainly a helpful workaround for seeing the actual errors, but it doesn't explain why I'm not seeing any lint-related messages from within VS Code itself. Shouldn't I see sections of code highlighted in the editor and have mouse-over explanations of the warnings/errors?

Comment: It was just to answer one of your questions which was whether the generated project was correctly configured for ESLint, so the answer is yes. Now, you know that the issue is in the VSCode plugin configuration. I'll try on my side at home but maybe you could get more help at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.